# Genetic Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization, genetic-algorithm, nonlinear-functions

I have a simple genetic algorithm that has to reach an optimal point of a trap function that is defined as follows:

```py
def R(x):
    n = len(x)
    m = int(math.ceil(n/3))
    s = sum(x)

    if (s==n):
        return 2*n*n,
    elif (s<(n-m)):
        return n*s-B(x),
    else:
        return 0,

def B(x):
    i = 0
    n = len(x)
    mbs = 0

    # loops over all the variables
    while (i<n):

        k = i
        while (k<n and x[k]==0):
            k = k + 1

        #print("k="+str(k))

        j = k
        while (j<n and x[j]==1):
            j = j + 1

        if (j-k>mbs):
            mbs = j-k

        #print("j="+str(j))

        i = j

    return mbs
```

I've thought to augment a lot the pop size and "hope" to generate with the `random.seed()` the optimal individual in the first generation and then just propagate the number of copies of it. For doing this I would just consider a tournament selection with a "big" window for the tournament.

This solution works only with 5 and 10 attributes but doesn't work with 30. The point is that I don't know how to solve the 30 attributes case.
Hoping that someone is able to help me.

Comment: A few things might help clarify your question here. 1. could you describe what x is? It looks like an array of integers to me based on how you're using it, is that correct? 2. What is B(x)? 3. If you are hoping to generate the optimal individual in a single generation, why are you trying to use a genetic algorithm? That defeats the point of using a genetic algorithm in the first place

Comment: I've update the post with the B(x) definition. The individual is a vector of binary genes. The optimal solution is given by all the ones, but the fitness function allow the GA to go in such a direction only if the vector as at least 2/3 of the values equal to one. Otherwise it carries you to a  local optimal point. I don't know how to avoid to reach such a local optimal.

Answer (score 2):

> I can use only a simple GA with some elitism...

Given this constraint you can increase population size without using elitism, but it won't scale well.

zegkljan's idea of using novelty search, seems better and can be followed without altering the search engine.

Just change the fitness function:

```
score(i) = (1 − ρ) · fit(i) + ρ · nov(i)
```

`fit(i)` is your `R` function normalized:

```
fit(i) = (R(i) - Rmin) / (Rmax - Rmin)
```

and `nov(i)` is the normalized novelty function (you have to keep an archive of already seen individuals, but this doesn't entail modifications to the 'engine').

`ρ ∈ [0,1]` controls the relative importance of fitness and novelty.

For further details about this technique: [When Novelty is not Enough](http://people.idsia.ch/~tino/papers/cuccu.evostar11.pdf) (Giuseppe Cuccu, Faustino Gomez)

Comment: Now I try it! Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Trap functions and similar are just a problem for GAs.

One possible workaround might be to use a multi-objective evolutionary algorithm (MOEA), e.g. NSGA-II, and add a second objective which would be a "uniqueness" of the individual, e.g. an average hamming distance from the other individuals in the population, or a . This will force (kind-of) the evolution to explore other areas of the search space as well.

Have a look at [novelty search](http://eplex.cs.ucf.edu/noveltysearch/userspage/). It's about abandoning the objective completely (for driving the evolution, but you still use it to find the best solution) and using just a "uniqueness" (called) novelty, to drive the search.

Comment: I can use only a simple GA with some elitism... now I'm trying to use a really big population size around 10000 for individual with 30 attributes.